# Download captured image on IOS

Tags: javascript, ios

On a website I need to capture a photo from user's camera and then download in. Here is my current code (I am using Vue):

```
initCamera() {
  let video = this.$refs.video;
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    if (navigator.mediaDevices && navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia) {
      navigator.mediaDevices
        .getUserMedia(this.constraints)
        .then(stream => {
          video.src = window.URL.createObjectURL(stream);
          video.play();
          resolve(stream);
        })
        .catch(error => reject(error));
    }
  });
},
capture(badgeId) {  
  let video = this.$refs.video;
  let canvas = this.$refs.canvas;
  let context = canvas.getContext("2d");

  context.drawImage(video, 0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
  let link = document.createElement("a");
  link.download = badgeId + "_" + Date.now().toString();
  link.href = canvas.toDataURL("image/jpeg");
  document.body.appendChild(link);
  link.click();
  document.body.removeChild(link);
}
```

`initCamera()` is called when page is created and `capture()` is called when on user click. This works with web cameras on Windows and on android devices. But on IOS (Safari and chrome) instead of downloading an image browser just opens a new tab with string from `window.URL.createObjectURL()` as an url. Why it is not working on IOS?